# How to reduce JSON object?

Tags: c++, sql, json, phpmyadmin

I have a JSON file created from a SQL query on a database. I'm trying to reduce several lines of the same "car_id" into a single line.
There is an example of my JSON file with several lines for a single :

```
[{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"1","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"2","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"3","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"4","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"5","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"6","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"}]
```

I searched in StackOverflow, Google, and either I did not understand how to reduce this file into this.

```
{"car_id":"1","sca_multiverseid":"430690","car_convertedmanacost":"2","car_coloridentity":"W","ccal_capacity":null,"clel_legality":"1,2,3,4,5,6","csul_supertype":null,"ctyl_type":"7","cstl_subtype":null,"set_block":"2","car_layout":"7","car_power":"0","car_toughness":"0"},
```

Here, there is only one different field to merge (clel_legality), but there can be several fields with different values (like (car_coloridentity, ccal_capacity, csul_supertype ...)

I'm sorry for my English if I made a mistake. Thank you in advance.

Edit : 
There is my SQL Query :

```
SELECT car_id, sca_multiverseid, car_convertedmanacost, car_coloridentity, ccal_capacity, clel_legality, csul_supertype, ctyl_type, cstl_subtype, set_block, car_layout, car_power, car_toughness
FROM mag_card A LEFT JOIN mag_setcard B ON A.car_id = B.sca_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_cardcapacityli C ON A.car_id=C.ccal_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_cardlegalityli D ON A.car_id=D.clel_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_cardsupertypeli E ON A.car_id=E.csul_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_cardtypeli F ON A.car_id=F.ctyl_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_cardsubtypeli G ON A.car_id=G.cstl_card
    LEFT JOIN mag_set H ON B.sca_set=H.set_id
```

Comment: what programming language are you using? Did you actually try to write any code? If so, please show it. It shouldn't be hard to use a loop to do this. What are you stuck on, exactly? P.S. `"clel_legality":"1,2,3,4,5,6"` is not a good structure really. Consider making it an array of numbers rather than a comma-separated string. Much easier to make use of afterwards.

Comment: I used a SQL query on Phpmyadmin to generate the table, and I exported it to JSON.

Comment: Yes. But my question was about what language are you going to be using to reduce the JSON? And what attempt have you made so far to try and do this reduction, or research how you might go about it? (Also it would be helpful if you showed us the query you used, for context.)

Comment: The goal is to parse JSON in C++ to be able to create graphs on this data. So I had to export JSON directly from PhpMyAdmin.
I have a PHP script that executes the SQL query and fetches the data but I don't know how to process the data efficiently.
I have about 258000 lines in input and I must technically have about 18000 lines in output.
I'm not attached to any particular language, I'm just looking for a method to merge lines efficiently and quickly.

Comment: Use "select distinct" in your SQL to avoid duplicates in SQL result. But there is such a need to use distinct, then you should suspect something wrong in the middle. Your SQL is probably incorrect, or data is incorrectly added to database. If data is correctly inserted into DB you should not get that duplicates.

Comment: You may want to look into using mysql's `Group_CONCAT` functionality. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/)

Comment: I can't modify the database and the separate select is useless because I only have different lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's to Caleb McNevin :

```
SELECT car_id, sca_multiverseid, car_convertedmanacost, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT car_coloridentity), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ccal_capacity), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clel_legality), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT csul_supertype),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ctyl_type), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cstl_subtype), set_block, car_layout, car_power, car_toughness
FROM mag_card A LEFT JOIN mag_setcard B ON A.car_id = B.sca_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_cardcapacityli C ON A.car_id=C.ccal_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_cardlegalityli D ON A.car_id=D.clel_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_cardsupertypeli E ON A.car_id=E.csul_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_cardtypeli F ON A.car_id=F.ctyl_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_cardsubtypeli G ON A.car_id=G.cstl_card
                LEFT JOIN mag_set H ON B.sca_set=H.set_id
GROUP BY car_id
```

The command GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT xxx) combined a and a GROUP_BY(primary_key) at the end of the request has worked!